# Gateway NE56R & mouse swipe gesture...how to disable?

Tags: windows-7, mouse

Can anyone tell me how to shut off the swipe gesture mechanism on my computer? It's driving me crazy. I cannot use a single application without having my computer screen minimize every time I move my hand over the mouse following a mouse-click, pointer movement, etc. Having to maximize my spreadsheets, documents, and applications so much is undercutting my productivity. How some  software engineer/inventor imagined that this mouse/gesture swipe gimmick would be helpful to computer users is inconceivable to me. It is a massive annoyance. I've found instructions online for disabling this obnoxious feature, but all the instructions involve messing with my registry, which I don't want to do. I will be SO GRATEFUL to any techie who can tell me how to disable this horrible mouse swipe mechanism without having to alter my registry! I'm using a Gateway NE56R Notebook, Windows 7 operating system, and an Inland USB Mouse (model no. 37535). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just press the F6 key by itself (no Fn key) to turn off the touchpad on this model.  My wife got this information from Gateway, and it worked.